# iscroll rubber band effect in jQTouch

Tags: jqtouch, iscroll4

I am a new developer and am trying to create a jQTouch application to display some scrollable content throughout multiple pages. I've decided to use iscroll and it only works fine on the home page. I've read that I need to refresh iscroll after each page but I am completely lost on how to do this. Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myScroll, myScroll2;
    function loaded() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper1');
        }, 100);
        setTimeout(function () {
            myScroll2 = new iScroll('wrapper2');
        }, 100);
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
</script>
```

In my html I have a div `id="wrapper1"` which works fine until I navigate to the second page where the div `id="wrapper2"` has the rubber band effect.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't figured this out yet (although I'm sure you have), you want:

```
myScroll.refresh()
```

or

```
myScroll2.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got this working. To get jQTOuch and iScroll to play nice with each other, the scrolling areas on the page need to be reset each time JQTouch makes them disappear. In other words, once you hide the div, iScroll doesn't know what to scroll the next time it's made visible. So as a result, you get the infamous rubberband effect. To solve this, just add an event listener that resets the scrolling area right after the div is called. Make sure you give it 100 to 300ms delay. This code below assumes your variable is called `myScroll`:

```
$(".about").tap(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){myScroll.refresh()},300);
});
```

And on a side note, here's how to establish multiple scrollers using iScroll:

```
var scroll1, scroll2;
function loaded() {
    scroll1 = new iScroll('wrapper1');
    scroll2 = new iScroll('wrapper2');
}
```